# Adding restrictions together in a linear program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have a linear program

$\max 3x_1+x_2\quad$ s.t.
$\quad\begin{matrix}
 x_1-x_2&\leq& -1\\
-x_1-x_2&\leq& -3 &(*)\\
2x_1+x_2&\leq& 2&(**)\\
x_1,x_2&\geq& 0
\end{matrix}$

I solved this and got $x_1=1, x_2=2$ for the optimal solution, but after a second look at the restrictions, I noticed that when adding $(*)$ and $(**)$ I get $x_1\leq -1$. Isn't this a contradiction to $x_1\geq 0$?

Comment: You are right. It seems that the problem is infeasible.

Comment: Yes. And the "optimal" solution the solver gave you violates (**). Strange that it didn't detect infeasibility since it doesn't seem to be a complicated LP, and all coefficients are "nice" integers

Comment: Thitd constraint: $2\cdot 1+2 \not\leq 2$

Comment: Sorry, right I just noticed I got the optimal solution by replacing $(**)$ with $2x_1+x_2\leq 4$. This was the point of the exercise, it makes sense now.